# Anyone knows references summarizing the history of supercomputing?

Tags: parallel-computing, hpc

Anyone knows references summarizing the history and ideas behind supercomputing including mentioning of developments in parallel programming languages, applications, startup companies (some was establish but didn't survive), needs of industry, etc.

Comment: Good one, I was curious as well.

Comment: The first chapter of [Michael Quinn](http://www.amazon.com/Parallel-Programming-C-MPI-OpenMP/dp/0072822562)'s book gives you a litle bit of the stuff you mentioned but not in great detail.

Comment: @Nunoxic:  Quinn's book is ok, but unfortunately it really doesn't talk very much about the developments in the past 10 years, where a lot of rapid development took place.

Answer (score 1):

I will collect here some interesting references:

The Landscape of Parallel Computing Research: A View from Berkeley (2006)
http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-183.pdf